# Property Feed for Website

Tags: php, xml, feed

I'm looking at building a website which shows local properties (UK Towns), the main aspect is getting an idea on how to automatically populate the website via the independent estate agents websites.

I.E how does Rightmove automatically populate its listings?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rightmove doesn't 'automatically' populate its listings. Agents upload their properties to Rightmove in one of two ways:

1) Directly - using the agent website, [RMPlus](https://www.rightmove.co.uk/rmplus/login/login.action)

2) Using the Rightmove [ADF](http://www.rightmove.co.uk/adf.html)

The ADF uses feeds provided by - surprise surprise - feed providers!! The biggest feed that Rightmove handle is from [Vebra](http://www.vebra.com/vebra/). I think the files are in .blm format.

Disclaimer: I used to work for Rightmove in a technical capacity. I left in 2012 so things may have changed, but I doubt it.