# How do big players import and process XML and data feeds?

Tags: xml, processing, bulk

I'm wondering what the backend processing is for websites like Rightmove, Prime Location, Realtor.com and others that process hundreds of daily XML feeds.

Do they have bespoke written programs handling the import, matching and updating of data, or is there an industry standard software?

How do they schedule these feeds and handle errors?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I used to work for Rightmove but left in 2012. I expect things are still similar, if not very much the same.

Rightmove have a bespoke system for the processing of feeds. They handle A LOT of feeds every day which are monitored using various tools. Feeds can 'hang' if errors are found, but these are usually worked through manually very quickly by their support team. AFAIK, there is no standard software for RECEIVING these feeds, only the standards set by companies such as Vebra that send the feeds in the first place (and Vebra are by FAR the biggest feed provider to Rightmove).

You can view a previous answer of mine to a similar question here: [Property Feed for Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385461/property-feed-for-website/24846405#24846405)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've sent you an email.

Comment: I never received an email.

Comment: I sent it through your website.